# Why is this typecasted variable calling function of subclass?

Tags: java, casting

I have four classes below.

Class Note:

```
public class Note {

    Pitch primaryPitch = new Pitch();
    static Pitch secondaryPitch = new Pitch();

    Note() {
        System.out.println("Tune()");
    }
    static void pitch() {
        System.out.println("Note.pitch()");
    }
    void volume() {
        System.out.println("Note.volume()");
    }
}
```

Class Tune:

```
public class Tune extends Note{

    Tune()  {  
        System.out.println("Tune()");  
    }

    static void pitch()  {  
        System.out.println("Tune.pitch()");  
    }

    void volume()  {  
        System.out.println("Tune.volume()");  
    }

    void rhythm() 
    {
        Note note = (Note) this;
        note.volume(); 
    }
}
```

Class Song:

```
public class Song extends Tune{

    void volume()  {  
        System.out.println("Song.volume()");  
        }
    }
```

Class Test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Note note2 = new Song();
            ((Tune)note2).rhythm();
}
```

When I run main, I expect the output `Note.volume()`.  The reason I expect that output is because in the Tune class, when I call `note.volume();`, note has been typecast to a Note object, so I expect to use the Note class volume() method call.  Instead I get `Song.volume()` which means I am using the Song class volume() method call.

My question is, why do I get `Song.volume()` and not `note.volume();`?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should learn about polymorphism, because it explains that behavior.

Comment: Because `Song` overrode `volume`, and that's how overrides work - they polymorphically call through to the implementation in the actual runtime type of the object, not the compile-time type of the pointer expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because note is an object of type Song().  The fact that you cast it to a parent type does not change the polymorphic behavior of the volume() method.  This is evident if you run the code in your IDE, and in Tune.Rhythm(), look at the variable values:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`this` means current **instance** `Song`, even you cast to `Note`, it's still `Song` instance

> by the way, In the runtime, **Java** doesn't have type, so `cast` in the runtime is meaningless. `cast` is just fro `Compiler` to infer type by context.

Since `Song` also `extends` from `Note` by `extends` from `Tune`, 
and `Override` `volume` method, so `this.volume()` will invoke the `Override` `Song.volume` method.

And if need to call the `parent` class `Note.volume`, need to use `super` with `volume` method, like: `super.volume()`.